# Windows File decryption fails after PC reset

Tags: windows, security, encryption, efs, decrypt

I have some Files which I saved in an encrypted format on one of my drives.
Last week I did a full reset of my pc and now I wanted to access those files. Sadly I cannot decrypt the files anymore.

I tried to:
right-click the file => properties => advanced =>
uncheck "encrypt contents to secure data" =>
ok => apply.

[and then I get this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSYgr.png)

I did the encryption a while ago, so it is possible that I do not remember all the steps correctly, but it looks to me as if the reset of my PC lost the key.

Answer (score 2):

You've reset the OS, so the encryption keys are now gone.

You have to either:

- Restore the files from an unencrypted backup, or
- Restore the OS from backup and decrypt your files, or
- Import the certificate if you have it backed up

Comment: "Certificate" in this case means "Certificate and matching private key". The certificate alone will not help.